# Split string into array by K?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to split a string into an 2d array based on `k`.

I know how to split it into individual strings or by regex.

How do you go about splitting it like this;

```
String text = "thisismyp";

// Result (where k = 3): 
char[][] = {
  {'t','h','i'},
  {'s','i','s'},
  {'m','y','p'}
};
```

Comment: Write a regex that takes groups of 3 chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.{k}` should work where you have to compose the regex yourself inserting the value of k into it.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to split the input and then get a 2D array. Could you show how that could be accomplished with the pattern `.{k}`?

Comment: Thanks used; Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\G.{3})");
  String[] result = splitter.split(plaintext);

Answer (score 0):

The regex is:

```
(.{3})
```

Nice and simple. You can add case insensitivity, newline handling, etc, according to your use case.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to split the input and then get a 2D array. Could you show how that could be accomplished with the pattern `(.{3})`?

Comment: In a single line? Why bother? Once you've got it split into an array, each element of which is a string with 3 characters, a simple for loop can be used to split that into a 2D array.

Comment: Is that 'single line' comment for me? I didn't say anything about a single line. I simply asked how you would employ the pattern `(.{3})` to get a 2D array of characters from a given string. You answer is a bit like answering the question _"how to build a house?"_ with _"by using tools"_. You may very well be technically right, but I was only curious to see what you meant exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, so maybe you need to change a little bit, but I think that this will work:

```
public String[] split(String str, int k)
{
    String[] a = new String[Math.ceil((double)str.length() / (double)k)];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += k)
    {
        a[i / k] = str.substring(i, Math.min(i + k, str.length()));
    }
    return a;
}
```

If you want it really as a char matrix, use something like this:

```
public char[][] split(String str, int k)
{
    char[][] a = new char[Math.ceil((double)str.length() / (double)k)][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += k)
    {
        String part = str.substring(i, Math.min(i + k, str.length()));
        a[i / k] = part.toCharArray();
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a regex you can brute-force it.  Brute force is faster but in your case I wouldn't worry about performance.  Still if anyone lands on this page and is not using a language with easy regex support; here is the fast Java implementation, embedded within a complete application you can compile and run.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Split {

    private static int K = 3;

    /**
     * Splits a string into a 2-D array of chars.  An array or list of strings would
     * be better, but <strong>the OP asked for an array of array of chars!!!
     */
    public static char[][] split(String s) {
        char[][] result = new char[(s.length() + (K-1)) / K][K];
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            result[row][col] = c;
            if (col == K - 1) {row++; col = 0;} else col++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Sorry about the hideous copy/paste
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("1")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("12")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("123")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("1234")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("12345")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("123456")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("1234567")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("12345678")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("123456789")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(split("1234567890")));
    }
}
```